# Prevent Video screen capture in VideoView Activity - Android

Tags: android, screenshot, screen-grab

I want to Prevent Video screen capture (screen graving) in my PlayerActivity, I use VideoView.

I already tried this

```
 getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
```

But it works only on some activity.

Comment: what do you mean by some activity? If you need to protect other activities then you need to put the same to those activities too.

Comment: Ya, ex. I have MainActivity and PayerActivity main activity is already protected, and this code doesn't work in PlayerActivity because it contains VideoView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `VideoView` with  `SurfaceView`, you can use `SurfaceView.setSecure(true)` it will prevent screen capture.

hope this will help you.